# Build circuit from a formula

Tags: logic-gates, boolean-algebra

I've this formula:

y = AB + AB'C + A'C

I've to build a circuit with only a 2:1 mux and a OR port.

I've done the truth table and k.map, but i've not idea how proced.

[image]

EDIT:
@jonk Thanks for your time and for an exaustive and complete answer. It's very usefull! Atm i've done this:

```
Y = AB + AB'C + A'C
Y = AB + C(AB' + A')
Y = AB + C( (A+A')(A'+B') )
Y = AB + C(A'+B')
Y = AB + C(A'B')
Y = AB + CA'B'
Y = (AB+A'B')(AB+C)
Y = AB + C
```

Then my circuit is:
Mux 2:1 with input A & B
Mux output enters into a OR PORT + C

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fB4dOV.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: please show your work. ... explain which part is giving you trouble ... schoolwork questions without demonstrated effort get downvoted.

Comment: I hope it is readable

Comment: the mux can be used to synthesize NOT, OR, and AND. Try some 2:1 mux configurations with your input signals A,B,C on the mux select line. also consider an additional fixed value input.

Comment: Exercise asks me to use only 1 mux and only 1 OR port. Im trying to mix variables: 2 of them as mux inputs and 1 for OR port input.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I want to start out by showing you something that in this particular case isn't much of a difference, but is an allowed technique just the same.

I moved rows 2 and 3 from your original map on the left side, downward, to get the new map on the right side. In this way, the \$B\$ column entries are collected together for the map shown on the right side.

Note that all the rows are still the same. No differences. All I've done is rearranged their ordering in the table.

$$
\begin{array}{lr}
{\begin{array}{ccc|c}
A&B&C&F\\\hline
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&1\\
1&1&0&\color{red}{1}\\
1&1&1&1
\end{array}}
& & & \rightarrow & & & & 
{\begin{array}{ccc|c}
A&B&C&F\\\hline
0&0&0&0\\
0&0&1&1\\
1&0&0&0\\
1&0&1&1\\
0&1&0&0\\
0&1&1&1\\
1&1&0&\color{red}{1}\\
1&1&1&1
\end{array}}\end{array}
$$

Again, this isn't that much of a help in this specific case because both examples are just as easily analyzed. So it's not necessarily an improvement. But I wanted you to see the technique so that you'd be able to use it in other cases where it may help more than here.

But in this case, by pure inspection of either the left side or the right side, you can see that the value of \$F\$ is exactly the same as \$C\$, with one exception shown in red.

So I think you can now easily see that \$F=C + A\:B\$ is correct.

You are allowed to make these kinds of row changes, if it helps you. You should practice this concept so that it becomes a little easier.

Doing it this way is kind of "hunt and peck," in the sense that there is no guarantee that you will instinctively see which rows to move where to simplify the expression. However, if you practice it enough then you will develop that intuition and it won't be "hunt and peck," as much as before.

And again, in this case, it doesn't make much difference. But in other cases, this idea may help a lot.

---

Now, if you aren't familiar with playing around using Karnaugh Maps, you should look into that. And in this case, it will be much more useful than the above technique. In fact, Kmaps are often helpful when doing this by hand, if the number of variables aren't too many (then the paper gets pretty busy-looking.)

For example, here is a K-map you might have started with:

$$
\begin{array}{lr}
{\begin{array}{c|cc}
\overline{C}&\overline{B}&B\\\hline
\overline{A}&0&0\\
A&0&1\\
\end{array}}
& & &  & & & & 
{\begin{array}{c|cc}
C&\overline{B}&B\\\hline
\overline{A}&1&1\\
A&1&1\\
\end{array}}
\end{array}
$$

Here, \$F=A\:B +C \$  almost stands out like a sore-thumb. So you can see that Kmaps actually can make this a lot easier to see without a lot of trouble. There are some nifty rules you can apply to Kmaps that are not unlike the earlier case where I moved rows around with your table, which can bring things into a clearer insights.

So, again, you should practice with Kmaps to gain skills there, too.

---

Finally, there is an algebraic approach you could take. That's already been shown in a comment by Cristobol, so I won't expand on that unless you don't follow one of slightly less well-known rules he applies, and you need further explanation.

---

At this point, you should find it a little easier to solve your circuit problem.

Comment: I want to vote this answer "up" twice... Well done answering and teaching how to solve next time :)

Comment: I'm always fascinated on how much time people put into their answers. Must have taken a long time to write all of this out... Especially tables with Mathjax... Yucky syntax haha. I always like the joke about LaTeX, "I have absolutely no idea what you're writing but it's the most beautiful thing I ever laid eyes on."

Comment: @KingDuken I answered it within about 15 minutes. (Though I did make a change, later.) I use Latex all the time, so it's easy. Most of the problems I have here are with being unable to use syntax I'd like to, because it's not supported.

Comment: edit: check first post!

Comment: @AndreaAngelini I don't see where the mux select line goes.

Answer (score -3):

It simplifies to C + AB.  Use the mux to get the AB term.

Comment: Perhaps you could offer a thinking process whereby the OP can learn to fish, rather than being given a fish?

Comment: Not sure.  The simplification seemed obvious from the Karnaugh map.  You could go through the algebra: AB + AB'C + A'C = AB + (AB' + A') C = AB + (A' + B')C = AB + C, but that's fairly straightforward as well.

Comment: I'll show you, then.

Comment: -1 for essentially giving away the answer. You should show steps and examples and help people learn, rather than handing them the answer. The OP has shown no attempt to go through the algebra or simplify which indicates they do not know how. So while it may be obvious to some, it isn't to others so it is best to teach the methods.